# JAVA(org.tinyradius) method addAttribute (org.tinyradius) on processing "Class" attribute

Tags: java, jsp, tinyradius

```
RadiusClient rc = new RadiusClient("xx.xx.xx.xx","0000");
AccountingRequest acc = new AccountingRequest("michael",AccountingRequest.ACCT_STATUS_TYPE_START); 
acc.addAttribute("Framed-IP-Address", "1.1.1.1");
acc.addAttribute("Class","Key CL: PT=C");
rc.account(acc);
rc.close();
```

i try to send an accounting request to my accounting server by create a jsp page as above.

However, only

```
 acc.addAttribute("Framed-IP-Address", "1.1.1.1")
```

can be accpeted, there is error occured while sending attribute type no.25 "Class" by using

```
 acc.addAttribute("Class","Key CL: PT=C")
```

where is going wrong ?!

Comment: the exception error showed "cannot set the value of attribute 25 as a string" ,however the method addAttribute is only accept (string,string)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i found the answer, attribute "Class" , need to be added by method :

```
    acc.addAttribute(new StringAttribute(25,"Key CL: PT=C"));
```